# Адрес отправителя в функции php mail

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Как можно поменять адрес отправителя в команде mail в php? Был выставлен

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mymail@mydomain.ru"
```

и всё работает но только когда вызываешь через браузер. Стоит вызвать из командной строки ( используя php `-f /путь_до_скрипта/` ) - отправитель становится `From: root@web` вместо `From: mymail@mydomain.ru`.

Comment: А вы никакую виртуалку не используете?

Comment: @doox911 виртуалку в каком плане?

Comment: `sendmail_path` нигде не переопределяется?

Comment: @doox911 нет. Он отрабатывает нормально когда заходишь на страницу с mail() .

Comment: Что значит заходишь на страницу с `mail()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. При обращении из `Apache` ( через браузер ) `php` использует файл настроек `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` . При обращении из командной строки используется файл настроек `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` . Требуется прописать аналогичную настройку во втором `ini` и всё работает корректно.

Comment: Я про это и говорил, а  у вас просто разные конфиги.